# Idiom for unacceptable request wrapped in what seems to be a nice offer

Tags: idiom-requests

Is there an idiom for an unacceptable request wrapped in what seems to be a nice offer?  For example, an offer for peace and not getting killed if one agrees to be a slave.

Comment: *Savvy*, since even if only a few accept, and you forcibly enslave the rest, you still have a perfect opportunity to spin it so as to appear wonderfully magnanimous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Sugar-coat the pill**

> [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/sugar-coat+the+pill)    To make something bad, unpleasant, or dissatisfactory easier to cope with, endure, or accept. The bosses are giving everyone an extra 10% bonus this Christmas, but I suspect it's a way of sugar-coating the pill that there will be massive pay cuts in January. I have to tell my mom about wrecking her car, but I need to find a way to sugar-coat the pill first.

Also known as "Sugaring the pill"

Comment: I like Robyn’s answer. I think it depends on whether what you are calling the “unacceptable request” is explicitly stated in the offer or not. If it is, I’d go with “sugar-coating the pill.” If it isn’t, you’re more into “Trojan horse” territory (and in that regard, Australians have a phrase with a similar meaning, “white-ant”).

Comment: I think sugar-coating works for me, but I will use the "poison in a honey jar covering" for the medieval theme. What do you think?

Comment: "poison in a honey jar" sounds really good (without 'covering') .

Answer (score 0):

**double-edged sword** [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+double-edged+sword)

> Something that can be both beneficial and problematic: good and bad

Answer (score 0):

I believe [bait and switch](https://www.google.com/search?q=bait%20and%20switch&num=100&newwindow=1&rlz=1C1PRFI_enUS771US771&source=lnms&tbm=nws&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjq36HTmdjbAhVEOKwKHWHTBfgQ_AUICigB&biw=1280&bih=588) is a good way to describe using a sweet offer in order to hook your opponent into something they otherwise might avoid at all costs. And there are many examples of the usage in that context, on *Google News*, because it's often said in reference to politics.